# Does propagation delay of a packet sent across a link depend on the link transmission rate?

Tags: performance

I was doing the exercises at the end of chapter 1 of *Computer Networking: A Top-down Approach* by *Jim Kurose* and came across the following problem;

> How long does it take a packet of length 1,000 bytes to propagate over
> a link of distance 2,500 km, propagation speed 2.5 x 10^8 m/s, and
> transmission rate 2 Mbps? More generally, how long does it take a
> packet of length L to propagate over a link of distance d, propagation
> speed s, and transmission rate R bps? Does this delay depend on packet
> length? Does this delay depend on transmission rate?

Propagation delay is the time it takes for a bit to travel from source to destination of a link. Here, it would be 2500 km/2.5 x 10^8 m/s = 0.01s. Now I'm confused whether I should add the transmission delay of (1000 x 8)/(2 x 10^6) = 0.004s to this since the question asks for propagation delay of the entire packet and not just one bit.

I've found differing answers on the net with some considering it and some not.

Edit: I understand the difference between the terms transmission delay and propagation delay. But I don't understand what propagation delay of a packet is and if it's any different from propagation delay definition with respect to a bit.

Comment: You're sending the bits in sequence, aren't you? So, the first bit arrives at `distance/propagation speed` and the last `size/transmission rate` later.

Comment: @Zac67 Your answer provided in the link made my understanding much more solid thank you. But I'm still confused whether propagation delay of a packet is sum of transmission delay and propagation delay of a bit or just the propagation delay of a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single definition for "propagation delay".

Kurose talks about "a packet ... to propagate over a link", so he refers to the transmission delay for that packet in whole.

More often, "propagation delay" is used in the physical sense, for the delay of a single bit being propagated over a link. It's more useful to understand the mechanics than to stick to certain phrases.

> how long does it take a packet of length L to propagate over a link of distance d, propagation speed s, and transmission rate R bps?

The packet needs to be serialized on the link (`serialization_delay = length/transmission_rate`). Then the bits need to propagate to the far end (`propagation_delay = distance/propagation_velocity`) and to be deserialized (which overlaps with serialization and propagation, so it doesn't count). In reality, some kind of processing is also required, causing a processing delay. This may or may not be neglected, depending on its magnitude.

Just a note to the book: the actual propagation velocity of light in fiber or an electromagnetic pulse in copper is more like 2x10<sup>8</sup> m/s, see [velocity factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_factor). For a radio or laser signal in air or vacuum, the speed is 3x10<sup>8</sup> m/s, of course.

Comment: Yeah I agree that terminology is not always important as we can call stuff whatever we like. Just to be clear, Kurose wants me to find only the time taken for the first bit of the packet to propagate across the link ie d-prop or d-prop + d-trans? In the first case my answer wouldn't depend on the transmission rate then.

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit, so I hope that becomes clearer.

Comment: Oh I see. So you've included both the transmission delay and the propagation delay in the answer. I'll go with that as well. Thanks.